# How to use easy_install to install locally?

Tags: python, import, installation, easy-install, pytables

I try to install [PyTables package](http://www.pytables.org) using easy_install.

My problem is that I am not root on the system and am not allowed to write to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` directory.

To solve this problem I decided to install locally. For that I have created a new directory: `/home/myname/mylibs`. Then I executed `easy_install -d /home/myname/mylibs tables`. As a result `easy_install` complained about the PYTHONPATH environment variable. To resolve this problem I added my new directory to the PYTHONPATH and repeated the previous command. As a result I get `syte.py` and `syte.pyc` file in my `/home/myname/mylibs` directory.

However, when I try `import tables` from Python it still does not work. What also worries me is that the new files do not have "table" in their names as well in their content.

Can anybody, please, explain me what is going on?

Comment: Maybe add the directory to your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently trying to use `easy_install` to put packages in a location I had write-access to. Like you, I had to add the location to my `PYTHONPATH` variable to get it to install. It was then necessary to set `PYTHONPATH` every time I wanted to run a command using the installed package(s).

For example, to install and use the `flask` package I needed to do this:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp easy_install -d /tmp flask
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp python -c 'import flask; print(flask.__version__)'
0.10.1
```

Without the `PYTHONPATH` variable set you'd get an error:

```
$ python -c 'import flask; print(flask.__version__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named flask
```

You can of course set the variable permanently by running:
    $ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp

Or putting `export PYTHONPATH=/tmp` in your `~/.bashrc` file.